# problem in understanding wrap_content function in xml

Tags: android

this is my code:

```
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="400dp"
   android:background="#D2B48C"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
   android:text="sahil"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="6"
   android:background="#DC143C"/>

   <TextView
   android:text="sahil"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="#DC143C"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

even though I have set the layout width for text view to be "wrap_content", it still covers the whole space set for linear layout which is 200dp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle your UI using weight then you should set width or height to 0. Otherwise, it will not work.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="30%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="50%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
            </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

It will look like:
[image]